# Adding columns based on common field pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if there is a way to add columns based on the common field in pandas.
This is my original dataset

```
      load       mapping      freq      99th        energy
61  175.0k     5CN0-5CN1   1.20GHz  0.937662  18952.056063
19  175.0k     5CN0-5CN1   2.10GHz  0.391280  19051.052048
```

I want to add the following columns `99th-1.20GHz` `energy-1.20GHz` `99th-2.10GHz` and `energy-2.10GHz` based on the presumption that `load` and `mapping` are the same.

This is the desired output

```
load    mapping 99th-1.20Ghz    99th-2.10GHz    energy-1.20GHz  energy-2.10GHz
175.0K  5CN0-5CN1   0.937662    0.39128 18952.05606 19051.05205
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use `MultiIndex` columns for this, e.g. via `pd.pivot_table`. You can flatten columns as a separate step, although your data will lose structure.

```
res = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['load', 'mapping'], columns='freq',
                     values=['99th', 'energy'], aggfunc='first')
```

Result:

```
                      99th                 energy              
freq               1.20GHz  2.10GHz       1.20GHz       2.10GHz
load   mapping                                                 
175.0k 5CN0-5CN1  0.937662  0.39128  18952.056063  19051.052048
```

Comment: But this way, I can't access 99th-1.20GHz `res['99th-1.20GHz']`

Comment: @tandem, You have a better option: use `res[('99th', '1.20GHz')]`.